# Material UI Autocomplete: Display part of selection

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, material-ui

I'm displaying three property values (option.primary_line, option.city, option.state, and option.zip_code) from state in the autocomplete suggestions; however, I'm trying to display only the option.primary_line value in the textarea when an option from the list is selected. I've tried setting the option.primary_line value to state and adding it as a value (tried defaultValue as well) to the textarea to no avail. What am I missing?

```
<Autocomplete
  id="combo-box-demo"
  options={addressSuggestions}
  getOptionLabel={(option) =>
   `${option.primary_line}, ${option.city}, ${option.state} ${option.zip_code}`
  }
  onInputChange={handleAddressLookup}
  freeSolo={true}
  renderInput={(params) => (
    <TextField
      {...params}
      variant="outlined"
      fullWidth
    />
  )}
/>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `renderOption` instead, and in `getOptionLabel` return the value you want to be assigned to the input

```
<Autocomplete
  ...
  renderOption={(option) =>
   `${option.primary_line}, ${option.city}, ${option.state} ${option.zip_code}`
  }
  getOptionLabel={(option) => option.primary_line}
  ...  
/>
```

Comment: Wow! I completely missed that in the autocomplete API documentation. I saw it, but passed right over it. Thank YOU!